# Get Mearest Time Using Date_Format MySQL

Tags: mysql, date-format

This is my code so far

```
    "select * from schedule_tbl where sname = '" & Label4.Text &"' 
and starting_time <= ending_time and ending_time >= starting_time
and day = DATE_FORMAT(Now(),'%W')"



starting_time        ending_time            day
 07:00:00             08:30:00              Tuesday
 08:30:00             10:00:00              Tuesday
```

It only returns the first record in the database. What I want is if the time now is 8:30AM then the next schedule will be show up is 8:30AM - 10:00AM. How can I do this with using my codes above? Or Is there any other way to make this happen?

Sample Schema

[image]

Comment: Sql Injection Warning.  https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i will do that later

Comment: Your query doesnt make sense . You say `ST <= ET and ET >= ST` isnt that the same?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current result and desire result.   Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: see my update with schema

Comment: waiting for current result and desire output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add the "I want the starting time to be less-than-or-equal to now" logic which can be accomplished by `starting_time<=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%T')`:

```
"select * from schedule_tbl where sname = '" & Label4.Text &"' 
    and starting_time <= ending_time and starting_time<=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%T')
    and day = DATE_FORMAT(Now(),'%W')"
```

Note that, as mentioned in comments, `ending_time >= starting_time` is redundant because it's satisfied by `starting_time <= ending_time`.

Comment: Well, was it supposed to return something? :) Does your table have a date that's after your local time and on Tuesday?